# how to preview rdlc report in devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress, report, rdlc, xtrareport

I've recently started with devexpress. 
Now, I'm trying to preview a rdlc report in devexpress. but, I couldn't manage it yet.

I've tried Xtrareport, it's ok. but I need to show rdlc report in devexpress.
Is there any control to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is **ReportViewer** control to do this.

If you can't find this control, please go to your project solution Properties and change the .NET framework to 4.0. Then you'll find **ReportViewer** control.